# How to automatically register validators in Fluent Validation only when they implement a certain interface?

Tags: fluentvalidation

I have some validation classes like:

```cs
public class AnimalValidator : AbstractValidator<AnimalDTO>
{
    // ...
}
```

And I would like to automatically register only the ones that implement an `IAutomaticValidation` interface to be used to validate DTOs received by the controllers.

I tried doing:

```cs
builder.Services.AddController( /* ... */ ).AddFluentValidation(options =>
{
    options.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<IAutomaticValidation>();
});
```

But it still looks for the `AbstractValidator` class instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do it with:

```cs
options.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<MyEntityValidator>
(
    x => x.ValidatorType.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x == typeof(IAutomaticValidation))
);
```

But then decided to use annotations instead:

```cs
options.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<MyEntityValidator>
(
    x => x.ValidatorType.CustomAttributes
        .Any(x => x.AttributeType == typeof(AutomaticValidationAction))
);
```